# Why doesn't IMT hold for all compact sets?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

In my college's notes, it says for all compact sets, extreme value theorem holds but intermediate value theorem doesn't. I wonder why since I think the original proof of IMT for $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ will suit for all $f:S\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with $S$ compact.

The idea of the original proof is that $\forall m\in[f(a),f(b)]$, take $c=\sup A$ s.t $A=\{x\in[a,b]:f(x)<m\}$ and show that $f(c)\leq m$ and $f(c)\geq m$ hence $c$ is the target.

But I can't see in which part of the original proof will it go wrong for compact set.

Comment: Well, it has nothing to do with compactness : take $S = [a, b] \cup [c,d]$ with $b < c$. The set is compact but it is not **connected**, therefore IMT doesn't hold !

Comment: What does IMT stand for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hermes is correct. Compactness of the domain makes the EVT work. Connectedness of the domain makes the IMT work.

Your argument fails because general topological spaces do not have an order, so the concept of "supremum" is not defined. And even for most order spaces, there is no guarantee the supremum exists - that is a special property of the real numbers, not something that holds in general.

What makes the EVT work for compact spaces is that as you move in directions that increase (or decrease) the value of the function, compactness guarantees a limit to how far you can go, and that limit will come with a point.

What makes the IMT work for connected spaces is that you cannot make sudden jumps. The function values for disconnections need not have any relationship to each other. This function *on the rationals* is continuous:
$$f(q) = \begin{cases}0, &q\in \Bbb Q, q < \sqrt 2\\1, &q \in \Bbb Q, q > \sqrt 2\end{cases}$$
But for a connected space, changes must be gradual.